# Laravel - Exception thrown at Guzzle function when running seeder

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, guzzle, homestead

Running `php artisan db:seed` throws the following error: `GuzzleHttp\Exception\InvalidArgumentException  : IDN conversion failed (errors: IDNA_ERROR_EMPTY_LABEL)` at `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:384`

Never seen this error before and it doesn't appear to be an issue with my seeder syntax.

The partial exception trace is:

```
1   GuzzleHttp\_idn_uri_convert()
      /home/vagrant/code/companion-2.0/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:220

2   GuzzleHttp\Client::buildUri()
      /home/vagrant/code/companion-2.0/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:113
```

I'm running commands within a vagrant/homestead environment. Could this be a version incompatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with guzzle 6.5.0. See more info here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2448

Solution: downgrade to version 6.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to upgrade to the latest stable version ([6.5.2 at the moment](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases/tag/6.5.2)). We did our best to consider all possible installation details, so you should not have this error anymore.

If the error still occurs, please report it as a bug here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues.

Answer (score -1):

Right now, the best solution is update, the lastest version works fine

Comment: This is what [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285592/1364007) suggests.